# Can't install composer on php 7 error

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm using xampp v3.2.2 with php 7.1. I'm trying to install composer but I'm get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check your php.ini, you should have a 'allow_call_time_pass_reference' directive, delete it.

PHP.ini should be in xampp\php\php.ini

Comment: @MostafaHashem open a commandline, what is the output of 'where php.exe'?

Comment: @MostafaHashem can you please upload your php.ini and give me a link? Also tell me from which directory did you get that php.ini

Comment: @MostafaHashem Are you installing composer in the same directory that php.exe is in?

Comment: i believe the problem within the PHP because i ran php on cmd and got the same error !!!!

Comment: @MostafaHashem that makes sense, but that jus tmeans there is some wierd config in php.ini, xampp tends to do that,  can you upload it please?

Comment: the output on the command line is the same error , and i already remove it from php.ini file

Comment: @MostafaHashem try to re-download php directly from php website, check around in the php.ini to see what you actually need from it (server root, the directory of htdocs, etc) and put it in a new clean php.ini